# Google Drive file download via http

Tags: java, android, http, google-drive-api

There is a link to Google Drive file accessible to anyone without authentication. Is there any way to download that file using just link and some sort of http client? Most of examples around are relying on Drive API and file IDs, however I'd like to stick with more lightweight approach, at the same time no parsing web page that results from http get to the url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"If you want to share a direct link, simply change the format of the link from this:

```
drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing
```

To this:

```
drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

Note that you'll need to grab the file ID from the original link and append it to the end of the new link. 
With the new format, any link you share will automatically download to your recipient's computer."

http://lifehacker.com/share-direct-links-to-files-in-google-drive-and-skip-th-1493813665 //Jan 2014

Comment: Missing part to the answer (but key info is here, thanks): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog